# didFailProvisionalNavigation error not localized

Tags: ios, localization, wkwebview, nserror

I have a localized app. I use `WKWebView` and also make some network requests. All the app localization works as expected. But errors from `webView:didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError` are always in English. I haven't found any information about any bugs on `WebKit` or `Error` side, but localizedDescription is always in English. Why?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Just create WKWebView and assign its delegate to self;
2. handle `webView:didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError`;
3. Enable airplane mode, switch off wifi and try to load any page;
4. You'll get connection error with wrong localization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I have found [a confirmation](https://openradar.appspot.com/22818481), that it's an Apple bug.